# Expressing polynomial equations as a set of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vectors

Suppose the $4$-vector $c$ gives the coefficients of a cubic polynomial $p(x) = c_1 + c_2x+c_3c^2+c_4c^3$.
Express the conditions

$p(1) = p(2), p'(1) = p'(2)$

as a set of linear equations of the form $Ac=b$. Give the sizes of A and b, as well as their entries.

So far, what I've done was sub in the values and differentiate the polynomials and let it equal to each other after subbing their values.

I get

$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 = c_1 + 2c_2 + 4c_3 + 8c_4$

then,

$0 = c_2 + 3c_3 + 7c_4$

as well as

$c_2+2c_3+3c_4 = c_2 + 4c_3+12c_4$

then,

$0 = 2c_3 + 9c_4$

I am a bit lost oh what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have
\begin{align}
0c_1 + 1c_2 + 3c_3 + 7c_4 &= 0\\
0c_1 + 0c_2 + 2c_3 + 9c_4 &= 0
\end{align}

Now write these two equations of four variables in matrix-vector form.  You already know that $c$ is $4\times 1$, that is, $4$ rows and $1$ column.  What should the sizes of $A$ and $b$ be?

Comment: ahhh, so it will be $A = [(0 &1 & 3 & 7 ) (0 & 2 & 0 & 9)]$ , A = 2x4 matrix, C is [x1,x2,x3,x4] and b = [0,0,0,0] ? so 4x1 as well ?

Comment: Close, but the second row of $A$ is wrong, use $c_j$ instead of $x_j$, and $b$ is the wrong shape.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 2nd row of a is 0,0,2,9. Is b not 4 rows of zeros ?

Comment: No, $b$ should have one row per equation.

Comment: My bad, b is 2x1